# How to exclude poses of a wheel based robot which place behind of the porevious pose

Tags: robotics, kalman-filter, sensor-fusion

I am currently working on coding sensor fusion of a wheel based robot pose from GPS, Lidar, Vision and Vehicle measure. Its model is basic kinematics using EKF and no discrimination against sensors i.e. data comes in based on time stamp.

I have difficulty to fuse those sensors due to following issue;
Sometimes when the latest incoming data comes in from different sensor from a sensor gave previous state, the latest pose of the robot comes in behind previous pose. Therefore data fusion does not get so smooth and zigzag-ed as a result.

I would like discard data which plots behind/backwards of the previous data and take data which poses always forward/ahead of previous state even when sensor to provide the data changes between timestamp t and timestamp t+1. Since the data frame is global frame, it is impossible to rely on its x coordinate in minus to achieve this.

Please let me know if you had some idea on this. Thank you so much in advance.
Best,

Answer (score 0):

### Preliminary warning

Let me slip here a warning before suggesting posible solutions to your problem: be careful with discarding data based on your current estimate, since you never know if last measure is "pulling pose back" or previous one was wrong and caused your estimate to move forward too much.

### Posible solutions

In a Kalman-like filter, observations are assumed to provide independent, uncorrelated information about state vector variables. These observations are assumed to have a random error distributed as a zero mean gaussian variable. Real life is harder, though :-(

Sometimes, measures are affected by a "bias" (a fixed term, similar to the gaussian error having a non-zero mean). e.g. tropospheric perturbations are known to introduce a position error in GPS fixes that drifts slowly over time.
If you take several sensors observing the same variable, as GPS and Lidar for for position, but they have different biases, your estimation will be jumping back and forth. Scaling problems can have a similar effect.

I will assume this is the root of your problem. If not, please refine your question.

How can you mitigate this problem? I see several alternatives:

- **Introduce a bias/scale correction term in your state vector** to compensate sensor bias/drift. This is a very common trick in EKFs for inertial sensor fusion (gyro/accelerometer), that can work nice when tuned properly.
- **Apply some preprocessing to sensory inputs** to correct known problems. It can be difficult to tune a filter for estimating state vector and sensor parameters at the same time.
- **Change how observations are interpreted**. For example, use difference between consecutive position observations so that you are creating a fake odometer sensor. This greatly reduces the drift problem.
- **Post-process your output**. Instead of discarding observations, integrate them and keep the "jumping" state vector internally, but smooth the output vector to eliminate the jumps. This is done in some UAV autopilots because such jumps affect the performance of PID controllers.

Finally, the most obvious and simple approach: **discard observations based on some statistical test**. A chi-square test of the residual can be used to determine if an observation is too far from expected values and must be discarded. Be careful with this options, though: observation rejection schemes must be completed with a state vector reinitialization logic to resutl in a stable behavior.

Almost all these solutions require knowning the source of each observation, so you would no longer be able to treat them indistinctly.